# How to apply CSS to document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a program that will use Javascript to 'print' a value to the screen using 'document.write()'. The value printed is an integer. I am looking to be able to use CSS to apply styling to this integer that is being printed out. Below is some truncated sample code of what I have tried doing, but it isn't working (the program just quits:

```
var number = 5 //just for an example
document.write('<p id="jstext"' + number + '</p>')
```

and this is the CSS code I'm using:

```
#jstext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's wrong. See the correction:

```
var number = 5; //just for an example
//------------^ // Not sure but ; is a must in some places.
document.write('<p id="jstext">' + number + '</p>')
//----------------------------^
```

You forgot a closing `>` here.

Working snippet below:

```css
#jstext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script>
var number = 5; //just for an example
//------------^ // Not sure but ; is a must in some places.
document.write('<p id="jstext">' + number + '</p>')
//----------------------------^
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE: Do not use the previous method.**

The above method is totally wrong. It will remove all the event handlers and totally damage the DOM. A better way is to use:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
document.querySelector("body p:last-child").id = "jstext";
document.querySelector("#jstext").innerHTML = number;
```

**Snippet**

```css
#jstext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script>
var number = 5; //just for an example
//------------^ // Not sure but ; is a must in some places.
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
document.querySelector("body p:last-child").id = "jstext";
document.querySelector("#jstext").innerHTML = number;
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! It works now. One more question, what is the benefit of doing this over using innerHTML? Is there any difference in the output?

Comment: So it's better to use your method than innerHTML? :)

Comment: Depends on the case. Both are better.

Comment: My understanding is that document.write will force reloading of the entire document so innerHTML is preferable for performance reasons.

Comment: @DylanYoung This is a shitty way of changing code. I'll update the code right away.

Answer (score 0):

you can use es6 Template Literals :
document.write(`<p id="jstext"> ${ number }</p>`)

Comment: The problem was the missing `>` and the general approach using `document.write`. How does using a different way to create the string address the question?