# CSS not effecting text within Javascript which is using API Open Weather Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, openweathermap

Okay so I have setup a bit of Javascript using the API Open Weather Map.. so when it is below 10.C in Brecon, Wales, the page will say 'hello?'.

Then in CSS I have styled the text so it should be red and 30px.. but this doesn't seem to be working?

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            /* RESERVATION PIECE */
            body {
                color: red; 
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Brecon,GB&APPID=43990a6bc6681b5b8e5876a536514832",
            function(json){                 
                var temperature = json.main.temp;
                if (temperature < 283.15) 
                {
                    document.write('hello?');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176216/how-to-apply-css-to-document-write

Answer (score 0):

Basically when using `document.write` you're overwriting the whole document, including the CSS. It's always a good practice to instead modify the text content of elements. This works as expected:

```js
let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Brecon,GB&APPID=43990a6bc6681b5b8e5876a536514832';

$.getJSON(url, json => {
  if (json.main.temp<283.15) {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Below 10°C';
  } else {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Above 10°C';
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  color: red; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```